# How to write Content Transformations using xquery in marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a javascript function(.sjs) which will return a string.
Now, I've to write a xquery transformation which will be triggered through dmsdk. Xquery function will accept a json doc, inside this transformation i need to trigger that javascript function which will return a string. Now, I need to use that string as a uri to load documents..
I've no idea on xquery!!

```
myXquery transformation function(jsonDoc)
{
/////////////////
myJavaScript function- which return a string
load the doc using this string as uri
}
```

Comment: For XQuery content transformation, just want to confirm, you want to convert JSON doc into XML or STRING.

Comment: No need to convert, 1.get the json as input 2.get string from my javascript function 3. write that json with this string as a uri

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query:

```
    declare namespace local ="local";

    declare function local:transformation($json-input, $json-uri as xs:string)
    {
    xdmp:save(concat("D:\", $json-uri), $json-input)(:Here I saved file on local path, If you want to save on Marklogic-DB use-: xdmp:document-insert( $json-uri, $json-input) :)

    };
    (:1:)
    let $input := '{"menu":{"id":"file", "value":"File"}}'
    for $json-input in $input
    (:2 Call here your Javascript function for json-uri :)
    let $json-uri :="json_first.json"

    return local:transformation(xdmp:unquote($json-input), $json-uri)
```

Comment: How can I pass inputs to my javascript function from xquery??  `let $content :='{"fname":"Deepan","lname":"Chelliah"}'
  let $input := "fname,lname"
 let $actual := xdmp:javascript-eval(
         "var simple = require ('/wdsUtils.sjs');
          simple.createUri($content,$input);")

 return $actual`

Comment: Why you need to pass inputs to javascript function, Only you need to take URI from Javascript function